# Merging features on the same ID but other attributes combined

Tags: qgis, arcmap, merge, dissolve

I have a layer with data:

```
ID | Attribute1 | Attribute2
1       x             b
2       x             c
3       y             d
4       y             e
5       z             f
```

I want to dissolve features based on the same attribute1 but attribute2 combined. Is it possible to do it qgis/arcmap?
The result i want to get is:

```
ID | Attribute1 | Attribute2
1       x             b, c
2       y             d, e
3       z             f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS, use [`Aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate) and set `Aggregate Function` for `Attribute2` to `concatenate` (see screenshot):

[image]